# Crackling Audio on All Aggregate Audio Devices with 2 or more devices

Tags: audio, midi

I am presently trying to combine two audio interfaces as an aggregate device (see devices listed below). Whenever I use more than one device in this way, my audio comes out crackling and low fidelity. This was working previously, however despite making no software / hardware changes, I have been unable to resolve.

[Video example of issue](https://youtu.be/Cn0Br2gykwY)

Macbook pro 11.6

- Elektron Digitakt (audio/midi selected in settings; latest firmware)
- Elektron Digitone
- Elektron Analog Heat mkII
- Stienberg UR22mkII

I have tried the following fixes

- Reset DVPRAM
- Change clock device / drift correct
- change device order
- change cables / power outlet
- Restart computer
- Ensure devices are set to same sample rate
- Try different usb ports

Comment: Just in case - try swapping 44.1 to 48 or vice versa.